# Error running executable jar - Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, jar, akka, maven-plugin, manifest.mf

In pom.xml , main class is mentioned in maven shade plugin and maven jar plugin to convert akka project into maven and make it an executable jar.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgbMQ.png)

But after running mvn clean install on that project and java -jar , I get this error: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaOfV.png)

Kindly help me in main class path to be added for maven jar plugin

Comment: Is your main class actually inside the JAR?

Comment: Can you elaborate @lexicore

Comment: Yes it is inside the .jar file - it has akkaexample folder and akkamain.class

Comment: Unzip your JAR file and check that there is `akkaexample/akkamain.class` file in there.

Comment: Try adding `<phase>package</phase>` to the `maven-shade-plugin` configuration.

Comment: @RomaJain Make sure your main class isn't extending any 3rd party classes.

Comment: @RomaJain i think your problem is lies in your class name, Please specify fully qualified name in assembly plugin like  <mainClass>com.stackexchange.stackoverflow.MainClass</mainClass>

Comment: @Afghan is the picture visible to you? SO in that project explorer,akkaexample is the project name.Inside that,src/main/java is the hierarchy.Then akkaexample is the package inside , akkamain.java is supposed to be the main class

Comment: @lexicore ,  i added <phase> then mvn package the project but still the same error

Comment: My main class is extending third party classes, what should be done

Comment: Try running with `java -jar -verbose:class <your.jar>` and check the output.

Comment: @Afgan It does not matter if main class extend 3rd party classes or not.

Comment: I ran with verbose command, still the same error.Can you guide me with class path

Comment: @RomaJain You should check the output. Is your class loaded?

Comment: @RomaJain I think we can't help you without a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make a minimal complete project which reproduces this error and share it via GitHub. I promise I will take a look.

Comment: @RomaJain I have a few projects which build an executable fat-jar with `maven-shade-plugin`. I can't see much difference to your configuration. So this must be something we don't see at the moment.

Comment: @RomaJain refer this link for main extending some other class [See it answer by Eric Leschinski](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366373/maven-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class)