# Cannot run jar in shell

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am having problem running a jar from shell command as i keep on getting "could not find or load main class error"

After dropping the jar file into my server. I execute following command

```
java -jar mapr.jar
```

But i get an error saying - could not find or load main class

Below is my project structure -

```
mapreduce (projectname)
 --src/main/java
    --mapreduce (packagename)
       --Map.java
          --ZipProcessor.java (main Class)
```

and my POM.xml file -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.project.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapreduce</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MapReduce</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>mapr</finalName>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>ZipProcessor</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I got my problem resolved using below plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    <mainClass>
                        com.application.ZipProcessor
                    </mainClass>
                </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: How did you create this JAR file?  It sounds to me like the JAR's manifest is referring to a class which is not present, that's all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven Error: Could not find or load main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366373/maven-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class)

Comment: Build using command prompt and resolve those error first

Answer (score 3):

```
<manifest>
     <mainClass>ZipProcessor</mainClass>
</manifest>
```

The above declaration of your main class should be done including package name and the class name.

If your package name is **com.test.processor** and your class name is **App** then the above declaration of main class should be as below :

```
<manifest>
     <mainClass>com.test.processor.App</mainClass>
</manifest>
```

Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: I got my problem resolved by using maven-assembly-plugin that packs jar-with-dependencies